# x86 disassemble, involves modular hashing

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, disassembly

I have commented what I think the code is doing.

I have tried putting `aaaaaaaaa`, `AAAAAAAAA`, `!!!!!!!!!`, and `000000000`, they all work. But it won't accept `bbbbbbbbb` or `111111111`. It seems the password accepts that all ascii character corresponds to `0x21`, `0x31`, `0x41`, ...

Initially, it calls `<getchar@plt>`, and it goes into a for loop, which accepts 10 characters.

After that, it starts a new loop, which I do not understand. Can you explain this loop? Is this doing modular division? Thanks in advance!

````
 8048443:   88 44 1d e5             mov    %al,-0x1b(%ebp,%ebx,1)
 8048447:   83 45 f4 01             addl   $0x1,-0xc(%ebp)
 804844b:   83 7d f4 09             cmpl   $0x9,-0xc(%ebp)                  # x ($ebp - 0xc) counter 9
 804844f:   7e ea                   jle    804843b <puts@plt+0xe7>
 8048451:   8b 45 f4                mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
 8048454:   c6 44 05 e5 00          movb   $0x0,-0x1b(%ebp,%eax,1)
 8048459:   c7 45 f4 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,-0xc(%ebp)                  # counter = 1
 8048460:   eb 15                   jmp    8048477 <puts@plt+0x123>         # start of the loop
 8048462:   8b 45 f4                mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
 8048465:   83 e8 01                sub    $0x1,%eax
 8048468:   0f b6 44 05 e5          movzbl -0x1b(%ebp,%eax,1),%eax
 804846d:   0f be c0                movsbl %al,%eax
 8048470:   01 45 f0                add    %eax,-0x10(%ebp)
 8048473:   83 45 f4 01             addl   $0x1,-0xc(%ebp)
 8048477:   83 7d f4 0a             cmpl   $0xa,-0xc(%ebp)                  # 10
 804847b:   7e e5                   jle    8048462 <puts@plt+0x10e>         # end loop
 804847d:   8b 45 f0                mov    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
 8048480:   89 c2                   mov    %eax,%edx
 8048482:   c1 fa 1f                sar    $0x1f,%edx
 8048485:   c1 ea 1c                shr    $0x1c,%edx
 8048488:   01 d0                   add    %edx,%eax
 804848a:   83 e0 0f                and    $0xf,%eax                        # only look at the lowest four bits
 804848d:   29 d0                   sub    %edx,%eax
 804848f:   89 45 f0                mov    %eax,-0x10(%ebp)
 8048492:   83 7d f0 03             cmpl   $0x3,-0x10(%ebp)                 # compare to 3
 8048496:   75 16                   jne    80484ae <puts@plt+0x15a>         # go to wrong answer
 8048498:   b8 b4 85 04 08          mov    $0x80485b4,%eax
 804849d:   8d 55 e5                lea    -0x1b(%ebp),%edx
 80484a0:   89 54 24 04             mov    %edx,0x4(%esp)
 80484a4:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 80484a7:   e8 98 fe ff ff          call   8048344 <printf@plt>             # correct answer
 80484ac:   eb 0c                   jmp    80484ba <puts@plt+0x166>
 80484ae:   c7 04 24 e2 85 04 08    movl   $0x80485e2,(%esp)
 80484b5:   e8 9a fe ff ff          call   8048354 <puts@plt>               # wrong answer```
````

Comment: FYI, commenting out and commenting are different.  The former means turning code into a comment block so it doesn't execute, and the latter means adding comments to augment the code.  You "commented" the code.

Comment: You left out the top of the first loop; `jle    804843b` jumps backwards to a few bytes before the `mov    %al,-0x1b(%ebp,%ebx,1)`.  I guess that's the getchar loop you're talking about?  Ugh, this is un-optimized code that stores everything in memory all the time.

Comment: The sar/shr part is doing `n %= 16;` with a signed integer type, which has to produce a negative remainder for negative `n`.  This is why you should use `unsigned` or write `n &= 15;` when you *don't* want that, and want it to compile efficiently.  It adds/subtracts 15 for negative `n` before/after masking.  Also, this shows your code was probably compiled by gcc4.7 or older; newer gcc are smart enough to use `cltd` to sign-extend EAX into EDX:EAX instead of mov/sar 31.  https://godbolt.org/z/tRLEkq shows the same code-gen from `return `n%16`.

Answer (score 2):

I was about to post an answer about the sar/shr/add/and/sub part of this code on [Reverse engineering code that does SAR by 31, shr, then add and subtracts that around an AND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61129022/reverse-engineering-code-that-does-sar-by-31-shr-then-add-and-subtracts-that-a) but it was deleted about a minute before I was done.  That part of the code probably pops up often enough to be worth answering:

---

**The code around AND is doing `n %= 16;`** for a signed 32-bit integer type (e.g. `int`), implementing C signed remainder semantics.  **For non-negative integers, it's equivalent to `n &= 0xf;`** i.e. keeping only the low 4 bits.

You can get GCC4.7 to emit exactly this code ([**Godbolt compiler explorer**](http://int%20mod16(int%20n)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20return%20n%20%25%2016;%20%7D)) for this function:

```
int mod16(int n) {
    return n % 16;
}
```

```
# gcc4.7.4 -O1 -m32 -mregparm=1  (first arg in EAX instead of on the stack)
mod16(int):
    movl    %eax, %edx
    sarl    $31, %edx
    shrl    $28, %edx
    addl    %edx, %eax
    andl    $15, %eax
    subl    %edx, %eax
    ret                     # return with n%16 in EAX.
```

Fun fact: gcc4.8 and newer use `cdq` instead of `mov/sar $31` to sign-extend EAX into EDX:EAX.  i.e. to set all bits of EDX = sign bit of EAX.

The store/reloads in your code, and using EBP as a frame pointer, indicate it was compiled without (extra) optimization.  GCC more than most compilers will still often use it's efficient ways to do things within a single expression.  I used `-O1` on Godbolt to avoid making the compiler store/reload to memory.

---

In C, `%` has to produce a negative remainder for negative `n`, but it's still much more efficient to emulate that around an AND instruction to implement signed-integer division semantics than to use `idiv` for powers of 2.  (Same deal for non power of 2 compile-time constants [with a multiplicative inverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183935/why-does-gcc-use-multiplication-by-a-strange-number-in-implementing-integer-divi).)

Recall that `(n/16)*16 + n%16 = n` for all `n`, and that C signed division truncates towards 0. (This applies for any divisor, not just positive powers of 2). So for example `-22/16 = -1` and `-22 % 16 = -6`.
`-1 * 16 + -6 = -22`.  A compiler has to emit code that works for every possible `n`; it (usually) doesn't know that your `int` is never negative when your code runs.

Arithmetic right shift rounds towards -Inf so it needs similar fixups to implement `/` division semantics.

**This is why you should use `unsigned` or `n &= 15;` when you *don't* need negative remainders, and want it to compile efficiently instead of to this over-complicated sequence.**  This extra cruft around `and $0xf, %eax` can optimize away if the compiler can prove that the value is non-negative, but that can't always happen (and never in a debug build).

---

This is part of the code from [someone else's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61126047/x86-disassemble-involves-modular-hashing) a couple hours ago, so we can supply the missing first instruction that loads EAX from `-0x10(%ebp)`

```
 804847d:   8b 45 f0                mov    -0x10(%ebp),%eax    # EAX = n;  you left out this insn

 8048480:   89 c2                   mov    %eax,%edx
 8048482:   c1 fa 1f                sar    $0x1f,%edx         # edx = 0 or -1  (sign bit of n)

 8048485:   c1 ea 1c                shr    $0x1c,%edx         # edx = 0 or 15
```

Logical right shift by 28 always shifts in zeros, instead of copies of the sign bit, so that turns `-1` (0xffffffff) into `15`.  (32-28 = 4 bits left at the bottom of the register).  And of course leaves 0 as 0.

So EDX = 0 or 15, for for non-negative or negative `n`.

```
 8048488:   01 d0                   add    %edx,%eax
 804848a:   83 e0 0f                and    $0xf,%eax                        
# only look at the lowest four bits
 804848d:   29 d0                   sub    %edx,%eax
```

It adds/subtracts 15 (or 0) around the AND.

This is an optimized way to do `-((-eax) & 15)` for negative inputs, based on the 2's complement identity that `-x = ~x + 1` combined with `&`.

Note that `x & 0xf` results in a number in the [0..15] range, so that minus 15 will always be negative or zero.  If the input was already a multiple of 16 (even if negative because that's how 2's complement works), the low bits will be 0 to start with.  So (n + 15) & 15 = 15, and 15-15 = 0, the correct result for `-128 % 16` for example.

For originally-negative inputs, this is just adding/subtracting 0, the additive identity which leaves the value unchanged.  So the whole thing is equivalent to `n & 0xf` for non-negative `n`.

The whole thing is equivalent to `(eax < 0) ? -((-eax) & 15) : (eax & 15)`

GCC using it for `n % 16` also shows it gives the right result for every possible `int`.  (There are no `n` values that have C undefined behaviour for `n % 16`).

---

```
 804848f:   89 45 f0                mov    %eax,-0x10(%ebp)    # store back into where we loaded from
```

So we know it's `n %= 16;` because it's storing the result back on top of the stack slot it loaded from originally.

```
 8048492:   83 7d f0 03             cmpl   $0x3,-0x10(%ebp)                 
# compare to 3
```

Yes, that's right.  FLAGS are set according to `n - 3` because AT&T syntax is backwards.  But  ZF is set if they're equal.